# Corsair GTX USB drive slow loading using USB 3.0

Tags: usb-flash-drive, usb-3, corsair

Corsair GTX USB drive slow loading using USB 3.0.
This happens in every system I have. Windows 10 or 11.
I have 3 of these USB drives and they all do the same thing.
In the USB 3.0 port it takes 1-2 minutes to load all the files. Once loaded the speeds are fine. Using USB 2.0, the USB drive loads instantly.
The drives are setup with one GPT partition. USB drives have a few thousand files. This issue has to do with how many files are on the USB drive. The more files the longer the load time. With just a dozen or so files, it loads quickly.
This issue cannot be drivers, or a bad USB stick since it happens on multiple systems, OS'es, and multiple sticks.
Any ideas?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: A folder with thousands of files will always be slower to load, especially if the files are images or videos. Is this the difference?

Comment: I would agree that thousands of files may slow it down except for the fact that it doesn't happen when plugged into a USB 2.0.

Comment: I am asking if there is a way to speed up opening the flash drive when using USB 3.0. When I start file explorer it takes 1-2 minutes to open the drive. Works fine on USB 2.0. Once all the files are shown it works normally.